# memory ordering on a simple producer/consumer example

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory-model

I have understanding issues on the memory-model.
Here is the example (I tried to simplify it but it's still a bit long) I will base my question upon:

```cpp
#include <atomic>
#include <cassert>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <optional>
#include <random>
#include <thread>

constexpr size_t hardware_destructive_interference_size = 128;

constexpr int maxWait = 1000;
constexpr int experimentRuns = 100;
constexpr int experimentLength = 1'000;

static void waitRandom() {
    if (maxWait == 0) return;
    thread_local std::mt19937 gen{std::random_device{}()};
    std::uniform_int_distribution dist(0, maxWait);
    auto waitIterations = dist(gen);
    for (int i{0}; i < waitIterations; ++i) {
        [[maybe_unused]] volatile int doNotOptimize = 0;
    }
}

template <typename INPUT>
class Worker {
    using input_t = INPUT;
    using func_t = void (*)(input_t);

   public:
    Worker(func_t fun) {
        mThread = std::thread([this, fun]() mutable {
            while (!stop()) {
                mainLoop(fun);
            }
        });
    }

    ~Worker() {
        {
            std::lock_guard lk{mMutex};
            mStop.store(true, std::memory_order_relaxed);
        }
        mCV.notify_one();
        mThread.join();
    }

    bool ready() { return !mWorkerBusy.load(std::memory_order_acquire); }

    template <typename T>
    void submitJob(T&& input) {
        assert(ready());
        {
            std::lock_guard lk{mMutex};
            mInput.slot = std::forward<T>(input);
        }
        mWorkerBusy.store(true, std::memory_order_relaxed);
        mCV.notify_one();
    }

   private:
    void mainLoop(func_t& fun) {
        waitForJob();
        if (stop()) {
            return;
        }
        fun(input());
        completeJob();
    }

    void waitForJob() {
        assert(!inputValid());
        mWorkerBusy.store(false, std::memory_order_release);
        {
            std::unique_lock lk{mMutex};
            mCV.wait(lk, [&] { return inputValid() || stop(); });
        }
    }

    void completeJob() { mInput.slot.reset(); }

    bool stop() const { return mStop.load(std::memory_order_relaxed); }

    bool inputValid() const { return mInput.slot.has_value(); }

    input_t& input() {
        assert(inputValid());
        return *mInput.slot;
    }

   private:
    std::thread mThread;

    std::mutex mMutex;
    std::condition_variable mCV;

    struct {
        alignas(
            hardware_destructive_interference_size) std::optional<input_t> slot;
    } mInput;
    std::atomic_bool mWorkerBusy = true;
    std::atomic_bool mStop = false;
};

static void asyncProcess(int) { waitRandom(); }

static auto now() { return std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now(); }

static void runExperiment() {
    Worker w{asyncProcess};

    const auto start = now();

    int input{0};
    for (int j{0}; j < experimentLength; ++j) {
        do {
            ++input;
        } while (!w.ready());
        w.submitJob(input);
    }

    const auto duration = now() - start;
    const auto durationNs =
        std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(duration).count();
    const auto usPerSample = static_cast<double>(durationNs) / input;
    std::cout << usPerSample << "us/Sample" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;
    for (int i{0}; i < experimentRuns; ++i) {
        runExperiment();
        std::cerr << i + 1 << " experiment(s) done\n\n";
    }
}
```

[LIVE](https://godbolt.org/z/qnGf7Prxr)
Basically, the main thread produces data and a worker thread consumes them but they may not be at the same pace (producing is faster than consuming).
The "invariants" are:

- worker must finish its current task before starting a new one
- data must be available

One of my misunderstanding lies here:

```cpp
    void waitForJob() {
        assert(!inputValid());
        mWorkerBusy.store(false, std::memory_order_release);
        {
            std::unique_lock lk{mMutex};
            mCV.wait(lk, [&] { return inputValid() || stop(); });
        }
    }
```

What would prevent the `store` to be executed after the `wait`, leaving the program in an undesired state (possibly `mWorkerBusy` remaining `true` *ad vitam*, preventing the worker to be waked up)?

I've got the same issue with:

```cpp
    template <typename T>
    void submitJob(T&& input) {
        assert(ready());
        {
            std::lock_guard lk{mMutex};
            mInput.slot = std::forward<T>(input);
        }
        mWorkerBusy.store(true, std::memory_order_relaxed);
        mCV.notify_one();
    }
```

What would prevent `notify_one` being called first (for instance)?

[EDIT] follow-up posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76710027/follow-up-on-memory-ordering-on-a-simple-producer-consumer-example)

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but the `{0}` initializer definitely doesn't do what you think it does in C++.

Comment: @Blindly hum, what do you mean? Isn't it a valid way to initialize a variable when it's a fundamental type? What's the issue?

Comment: No, that's `{}`. `{0}` means "initialize the first element with 0, and then all other elements with 0", which can be shortened to just "initialize all elements with 0", which is `{}`.

Answer (score 1):

### 1. Mutex Synchronizes

> ```cpp
> mWorkerBusy.store(false, std::memory_order_release);
> {
>     std::unique_lock lk{mMutex};
>     mCV.wait(lk, [&] { return inputValid() || stop(); });
> }
> ```
>
> What would prevent the `store` to be executed after the `wait`, leaving the program in an undesired state (possibly `mWorkerBusy` remaining true ad vitam, preventing the worker to be waked up)?

The memory order doesn't guarantee you this. `std::memory_order_release` prevents reads and writes on the current thread from being reordered *after* the store, but the memory operations could be reordered before, leading to the problem you've described.

What actually protects you here is the `std::mutex`. When you lock a mutex:

> Synchronization: Prior `unlock()` operations on the same object *synchronize with* this operation.

- [[requirements.mutex.general]/8](https://eel.is/c++draft/thread.mutex#requirements.mutex.general-8)

> **9** An evaluation A *inter-thread happens* before an evaluation B if
>
> - A synchronizes with B, or
> - [...]
>
> **10** An evaluation A happens before an evaluation B (or, equivalently, B happens after A) if:
>
> - A is *sequenced before* B, or
> - A *inter-thread happens* before B.

- [[intro.races]/9](https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.multithread#intro.races-9)

Leading back to your example:

- `store` is *sequenced before* `unlock()` on the producer thread
- `unlock()` *inter-thread happens before* `lock()` on a consumer thread
- by extension, `store` *happens before* `lock()` on a consumer thread

In simpler terms, when you lock a mutex, you see what other threads have done before unlocking.

### 2. Loading Atomics Is Unsynchronized

**HOWEVER, there are some cases in your program with NO synchronization, and that can have unintended effects:**

> ```cpp
> bool ready() { return !mWorkerBusy.load(std::memory_order_acquire); }
>
> // ...
>
> do {
>     ++input;
> } while (!w.ready());
> w.submitJob(input);
> ```

This code is a mess. There is no form of synchronization, so `w.ready()` might be infinitely true in this loop, with the producer never seeing any change.
What might save you is:

> Implementations should make atomic stores visible to atomic loads within a reasonable amount of time.

- [[atomics.order]/11](https://eel.is/c++draft/atomics.order#11)

In case you're wondering *why* there is no synchronization: you're only loading a value. `std::memory_order_acquire` means that if we see one change to `mWorkerBusy`, we must also see the preceding changes. However, it doesn't guarantee that we read the most recent value.

**In general, no synchronization between atomics takes place as long as you're only loading.**

### 3. Condition Variables Synchronize

> ```cpp
> {
>     std::lock_guard lk{mMutex};
>     mInput.slot = std::forward<T>(input);
> }
> mWorkerBusy.store(true, std::memory_order_relaxed);
> mCV.notify_one();
> ```
>
> What would prevent `notify_one` being called first (for instance)?

Absolutely nothing. You're using `std::memory_order_relaxed`, so the operation can be reordered on the current thread past the `.notify_one()`. **This is a mistake! Never use `std::memory_order_relaxed` if order of loads/stores in relation to other operations is relevant!**

However, the condition variable performs some form of synchronization through the mutex. Whichever thread gets notified will acquire `mMutex`, and will see `mInput.slot = std::forward<T>(input);`, because it *happened before* `mMutex.unlock()` (implicitly called through the guard).

Even with the "wrong" memory order, we can hijack the mutex to synchronize anyway:

```cpp
{
    std::lock_guard lk{mMutex};
    mInput.slot = std::forward<T>(input);
    // the atomic store is now sequenced before mMutex.unlock()
    mWorkerBusy.store(true, std::memory_order_relaxed);
}
// mMutex.unlock() inter-thread happens before mMutex.lock(), elsewhere, which
// makes the change to mWorkerBusy visible
```

### 4. Fixing Design Issues

As you can see, your use of atomics makes very little sense in both **2.** and **3.**. You expect atomics to provide synchronization, but it's actually the condition variables and mutexes that do this.

A better way to synchronize producers and consumers is to use multiple condition variables:

- one variable for when the producer has output that can be consumed
- one variable for when the consumer is able to consume more input

The consumers and producers can then notify one another, and there are no memory issues if you properly use `std::mutex`.

Another threading primitive that is specifically designed for synchronizing producers and consumers is [`std::binary_semaphore`/`std::counting_semaphore`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/counting_semaphore), which would be much better tools in this case.

Comment: That's a mouthful... I'll take some time to digest this. Thank you.
Thanks also for the C++20 reference. Yet I'm stuck to C++14 on my use case (perhaps 17 at most).

Comment: I think that I misunderstand also what exactly mean "sequenced-before" in your "1". According to [order of evaluation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order#:~:text=expression%20is%20evaluated.-,Rules,-1)) is it rule 1 that applies? (full-expression).
Then is it only the "synchronize with" relationship that prevent the ```sequenced-before``` store to be reordered after the (implicit) ```unlock()``` ?
Without any synchronization relationship, ```sequenced-before``` expression can be reordered any way?

Comment: Regarding point 2: looping on a load, expecting a certain value that can happen only on given circonstances won't be a valid design to synchronize? I mean if loading some value implies that there is one and only one store that can have set this value, you know for sure which store synchronizes with which load? Thus establishing some synchronization? No?

Comment: Regarding point 4: do I need a different mutex for each condition variable (to avoid inter-deadlock) or can it be design with only one?

Comment: @Oersted sequencing happens within the same thread. Any full-expression is sequenced before another full-expression. It's the only thing which prevents reordering the atomic store around `unlock()`. And in general, sequenced-before cannot be reordered, unless the visible behavior of the program is the same (as-if rule).

Comment: @Oersted no, that loop is not valid design. It's an infinite loop on an atomic with no synchronization. An aggressively optimizing compiler can actually assume that you always read the same value, so the loop turns into UB. No compiler does that to atomics in practice though. And synchronization doesn't apply here at all. There is no synchronization as long as you only load from atomics, no matter what.

Comment: @Oersted it's safer to use just one mutex, because it's quasi-impossible to deadlock with just one mutex and lock-guards, unless you lock twice on the same thread. You can only use two separate mutexes if your buffer for passing data between threads is thread-safe, like a thread-safe queue. Otherwise, you can run into a data race when two threads access the buffer at the same time.

Comment: about "sequenced-before" and reordering: it's what I thought about; I have a full expression A sequenced before B but working on separate things, thus, according to the as-if-rule, A could be reordered after B, without knowing from their threads but with possible consequences if memory concerned is shared by another thread. Here one expression worked on an atomic, the other on a mutex, thus I expected a possible reordering. Yet there is the synchronization rule of the ```unlock``` (can it be seen as a kind of fence?).

Comment: regarding atomic vs condition_variable. I understand that we have few to no guarantee that a store will be seen by a load. Is there a stronger guarantee that a ```notify_...``` will be seen by a ```wait```?

Comment: @Oersted yes, synchronization with mutexes often involves some form of memory fence. It's correct to think of `lock()` and `unlock()` acting as a fence; namely `unlock()` makes changes visible to other threads, and `lock()` pulls in changes. It would violate the as-if rule to reorder something in and out of the critical section, because that prevents this synchronization.

Comment: @Oersted there is no guarantee *when* a `notify` will be seen by another thread which called `wait()`, so the problem is very similar to repeatedly `load()`ing an atomic. However, any sane implementation should make that `notify()` visible *eventually*, and the waiting thread isn't busy-waiting, which is very important.

Comment: By the way, A. Williams, "C++ Concurrency in action" devoted its chapter 5 to synchronisation with atomics, which may have increased my confusion. Maybe that your argument against busy-waiting is more important, yet, in my example, there is no busy-waiting I think. I produce a sample, test an atomic and go on...

Comment: @Oersted you're looping `while (!w.ready())`, but the condition depends on an atomic load, which has no form of synchronization. There is no way of telling how long you're going to spend looping at 100% CPU usage here.

Comment: The ```while``` here is designed to loop on the input, but maybe that I made a mistake when I simplified the example (this part is not very readable I confess).

Comment: FYI, the OP posted a followup on codereview.SE: [C++: algorithm that uses fixed-size buffer of data that are produced in stream, faster than the algorithm speed](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/286131) - you might want to take a look since you've already spent time understanding their code.

Comment: `mWorkerBusy.load(acquire)` will synchronize-with `mWorkerBusy.store(false, std::memory_order_release);` in `waitForJob` if that's where a "false" value came from.  If it's currently `true`, and we keep looping until we see a `false`, then we will definitely synchronize-with the thread that made it `false`.  ISO C++ does guarantee coherency and that loads observe values for a single object in an order compatible with the modification-order M.   (There is another function that does a `relaxed` store to the same variable, which is potentially sketchy; I haven't looked at the whole thing.)

Comment: Anyway, I've seen multiple answers from you where you raised strange concerns about atomics, in this case about "latest value" and prompt visibility.  ISO C++ couldn't find a way to *formally* guarantee anything about how fast values become visible, so the actual wording is just a "should", but all usable implementations will compile a `.store` to an asm store which (by hardware cache coherency) becomes visible within a few tens of nanoseconds to other cores (or more on cache miss + contention).  *Ordering* wrt. other ops is determined by the memory_order, but visibility will happen eventually

Comment: @PeterCordes the concerns are mostly theoretical, based on what an aggressively optimizing compiler could do with atomics, especially if it went slightly against recommended practice. `std::atomic` is quasi-volatile in practice, so this isn't as big of an issue. A `while (!a.load())` loop is still very sketchy due to busy-waiting, especially when this isn't a lock-free wait like a CAS loop.

Comment: A spin-loop on a load is often not desirable for power and efficiency, but there's zero correctness problem.  A C++ implementation that broke spinlocks and other spin-wait loops would be unusable in general for lock-free programming, and would violate the standard if finite loop durations become infinite at compile time.  True it's only a "should", but again, that's almost certainly because it's not something formal verification can check easily and because thread sched delays can be unbounded, not because they think it would be ok if an implementation hoisted atomic loads out of loops.

Comment: There are lots of real concerns to worry about with lock-free programming, so I think it's confusing and unhelpful for your answers to distract learners with concerns that aren't real-world, and arguably not even theoretically valid.